# "error: ‘PATH_MAX’ undeclared" when trying to make menuconfig

Tags: linux-kernel

I have an OVH cloud VPS with Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit server. I needed linux headers which OVH does not provide by default, so I found some tutorials on how to compile the linux kernel from source using the OVH config files, which should allow for compiling the headers from source also.

I was able to compile the first time using the 3.18.6 kernel and the OVH config file ftp://ftp.ovh.net/made-in-ovh/bzImage/3.18.6/config-3.18.6-xxxx-std-ipv6-64.

I updated grub and booted successfully with my new kernel. When I type `uname -r` I see my new compiled kernel `3.18.6-my-private-build-std-ipv6-64`.

However now if I attempt to compile the headers I get some errors:

```
HOSTCC  scripts/basic/fixdep
scripts/basic/fixdep.c: In function ‘parse_dep_file’:
scripts/basic/fixdep.c:322:9: error: ‘PATH_MAX’ undeclared (first use in this function)
char s[PATH_MAX];
     ^
scripts/basic/fixdep.c:322:9: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
scripts/basic/fixdep.c:322:7: warning: unused variable ‘s’ [-Wunused-variable]
char s[PATH_MAX];
   ^
make[1]: *** [scripts/basic/fixdep] Errore 1
make: *** [scripts_basic] Errore 2
```

I get the same errors any time I try to use make. For example, if I try to 'make menuconfig' I get the same errors, I can no longer compile the kernel like I did before.
I have read on various forum posts that other people that received these errors didn't have all the necessary packages (`build-essentials`, `libcurses5-dev`, etc.) I have all of the packages correctly installed and updated. Please help!

Comment: in kernel 3.3 source i saw this "./include/linux/limits.h:12:#define PATH_MAX        4096"

Comment: checking the limits.h file in my usr/include/linux directory I noticed that it didn't define PATH_MAX, so I added it in manually and now 'make menuconfig' is working again

Comment: I had the same problem with recent kernel (v5.0), so I removed all files from git and did `git reset --hard`.